# EntityFramework Core 2 - ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a scenario where my model has the fields CreatedOn and UpdatedOn and following what I found in the documentation of EF Core I implemented my class as follows

```
builder.Entity<Registro>(b =>
    {
        b.Property<DateTime>("CreatedOn")
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");

        b.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedOn")
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()"); ;
    });

public class Registro
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

On insert both fields are saved with the correct value, however the update it does not happen as I expected, the UpdatedOn keeps the save value. It also follows how I am doing the entity update

```
public void Put(Guid id, [FromBody]string value)
{
    var r = context.Registros.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    r.Nome = value;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: HasDefaultValueSql is literally setting the default value of the underlying SQL table. You would need to update the UpdatedOn property in your model before you save it

Comment: @DarrenLamb thanks I'm considering doing this, but what is the behavior of ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate? When **OrUpdate** will generate a value ?

Comment: It just lets EF know that values are generated for added or updated entities, it does not guarantee that EF will setup the actual mechanism to generate values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-or-update

Comment: @DarrenLamb thx,  now I noticed that I totally ignored the red boxes, I'll be more careful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get your UpdatedOn timestamp to update automatically, one method you could choose is to implement an interface describing the functionality and overload the DbContexts SaveChanges method.

```
public interface IUpdateable 
{ 
    DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }  
}

public class Registro : IUpdateable
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

And then within your Context class

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();

    // get a list of all Modified entries which implement the IUpdatable interface
    var updatedEntries = entries.Where(e => e.Entity is IUpdateable)
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified)
            .ToList();

    updatedEntries.ForEach(e =>
    {
        ((IUpdateable)e.Entity).UpdatedOn = currentDateTime;
    });


    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That is very interesting. Correct if I'm wrong, but since the entities are already in memory this shouldn't result in performance issues?

Comment: None that I've noticed. However someone may be able to correct me!

Comment: This will not work with the new ExecuteUpdateAsync/ExecuteDeleteAsync since these are not tracked in memory.